# IE9 or IIS Express is caching jquery and/or html content

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-9, iis-express

Im debugging a page with some jquery.  Using VS 2012 I use the "browser link" to start a debug session.  For some strange reason, some of the content is not showing the most recent content, yet if I switch the browser to Chrome, it shows up fine and no "stale" content.  The most telling evidence though, is that when using IE, if I click a button that interacts with the content in question, it suddenly shows the newer content.

The content in question is items in an ASP.net ListBox control.  They are hard-coded and not dynamic.  Ive turned off every browser cache I can think of.  Tried restarting  IIS Express and Visual Studio also, but same problem persists.  I cant tell if its IIS Express is caching or IE.

Suggestions?